# Formula disappear php excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to use a formula which is not implanted in PHPExcel but in excel, COUNTIFS whit 2 arguments.

I update the formula file in phpexcel and I add

```
$objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
```

To have no generation errors.

But when I open the file with excel I only have a 0 and no formula. I also have an open and repair and this remove the function I think

This is for example

```
$sheet->setCellValue($this->intToChar($j).($end+$i),'=COUNTIFS(E$17:F$47;$B58;E$16:F$46;$B58)');
```

If I just add

```
$sheet->setCellValue($this->intToChar($j).($end+$i),'COUNTIFS(E$17:F$47;$B58;E$16:F$46;$B58)');
```

and I set an = in excel it works

Thanks for your help

Comment: What Writer are you using? COUNTIFS should work with the Excel2007 Writer with $objWriter->setPreCalculateFormulas(false); but isn't a core function for Excel BIFF files so isn't available for the Excel5 Writer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explicitly states that commas (,) should be used as an argument separator for function arguments, unless you've explicitly set a locale for the calculation engine; so you need

```
$sheet->setCellValue(
    $this->intToChar($j).($end+$i),
    '=COUNTIFS(E$17:F$47,$B58,E$16:F$46,$B58)'
);
```

And why are you using a homebrew `intToChar()` function when there's a built-in PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() function?

Comment: It works and thanks for the tip with PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()